# vue.config.js to (laravel) webpack.mix.js

Tags: laravel, vue.js, laravel-mix

I started using Vue using the Vue CLI template. In that template you create a file called 'vue.config.js' to define some settings. More to find here: https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/css.html#css-modules

I had a settings for an global css/sass file so all my components could access the variables (the file only contains vars).

vue.config.js:

```js
module.exports = {
    // So we can use the template syntages in vue components (correct me if am wrong)
    runtimeCompiler: true,
    // CSS settings
    css: {
        loaderOptions: {
            sass: {
                // Load in global SASS file that we can use in any vue component and any sass file
                data: `
                  @import "@/assets/css/variables.scss";
                `
            }
        }
    }
};
```

Now I am working on another project. This time I use laravel and vue in one app. Laravel makes Vue works with webpack and webpack.mix.js.

Now here is where I get stuck. I can't create a config so the global css file with the variables can be recognises in the vue "one file components"  I can't find any solution on the internet or my own experience to make this work.

Anyone experience with this?

Comment: Couldn't you just use the .env file: https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/mix#environment-variables ?

Comment: that is only JS files, not in <style>

Answer (score 2):

Laravel mix has a shortcut to "indicate a file to include in every component styles" (look for **globalVueStyles** in the [option available](https://laravel-mix.com/docs/5.0/options)). So simply add the code below to the `webpack.mix.js` file at project root.

```
mix.options({
    globalVueStyles: `resources/assets/css/variables.scss`
});
```

And install the dependency **sass-resources-loader**

```sh
npm install --save-dev sass-resources-loader
```

It works only as relative path. Also, the docs say that this option only works when **extractVueStyles** is enabled, however it was not needed for me.

To have more control over "vue-loader" you can use the undocumented function `mix.override`

```js
mix.override(webpackConfig => {
    // iterate and modify webpackConfig.module.rules array
})
```

Comment: I would love to try this solution for my self. But I am now using c# (etc.). and I dont have the tools anymore (sure you can use laravel/vue in windows, but its different) to try this at home. Any people that wanna upvote/try this as well and confirm this is working?