# Sass Loader issue with Webpack and Laravel Mix 3

Tags: vue.js, webpack, sass, laravel-mix

I have a project that is using Laravel Mix version 3 (I cannot upgrade because of the known dynamic importing issue with Webpack 4).

In my webpack configuration, I have the following rule:

```
rules: [
    {
        test: /\.scss$/,
        loader: "sass-loader",
        options: {
            data: '$static-url: \'' + config.app.urls.static + '\';'
        }
    }
]
```

The purpose of this rule is to inject the `$static-url` variable into all SCSS compilations.

The above rule works just fine on any `.scss` files, however, it is not working on any inline `.scss` in my Vue templates. It works perfectly in other projects that are using the latest version of Laravel Mix, but I cannot get it to work in this project.

For example, it does not work with the following:

```
<template>

    <div class="foo"></div>

</template>

<style lang="scss" scoped>

    @import "~core-styles/brand/_variables.scss";
    @import "~core-styles/brand/_mixins.scss";

    .foo {
        background-image: url($static-url + '/assets/images/example.png');
    }

</style>
```

The above will output the following error:

> Undefined variable: "$static-url".

Can anyone suggest why this is not working?

***Just to re-iterate, this works on `.scss` files, it only doesn't work on my Vue templates...***

## Additional Information

I have the following versions defined in my `package.json` (only listed relevant packages):

```
"devDependencies": {
    "laravel-mix": "^3.0.0",
    "node-sass": "^4.12.0",
    "sass": "^1.23.0",
    "sass-loader": "^7.3.1",
    "vue": "^2.6.10"
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.6.10"
}
```

Comment: Here is what I [found](https://vue-loader.vuejs.org/guide/pre-processors.html#sharing-global-variables) . Try to use `prependData` instead. Do you use `vue-loader`?

Comment: @AndrewVasilchuk - I believe that Laravel Mix uses `vue-loader` internally so yes, it should be installed. I'll try this now and let you know how I get on. Thank you! :-D

Comment: @AndrewVasilchuk - unfortunately this does not work, I am getting the same error. In addition, `data` is for `sass-loader` versions before 8.0.0

Comment: maybe related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62250789/2932525