# Laravel Mix: How to copy files to a directory before proceeding to mix sass

Tags: laravel, webpack, sass, laravel-mix

So my use case is that I have a couple of different "themes" to be used in the laravel webapp. My plan is to use `mix.copyDirectory()` to copy the specific scss files for that theme before doing the actual `mix.sass` step. I set up a laravel .env variable to control which theme to include in the build.

I did something like this in `webpack.mix.js`:

```
mix.copyDirectory('resources/sass/' + process.env.MIX_THEME, 'resources/sass/build')
    .js('resources/js/app.js', 'public/js')
    .sass('resources/sass/build/app.scss', 'public/css');
```

The files copied to resources/sass/build include a `_variables.scss` that also gets imported by my Vue components. (So the components share the colors and other common styles)

Now, the problem I encountered is that upon first run (via `npm run dev`), I get errors that the `_variables.scss` is not in the build folder. Upon second run it's fine! So I think what's happening is that mix starts the copyDirectory, but proceeds to the js and sass steps before the copyDirectory finishes.

So my question is: is there a way to have copyDirectory wait to finish before proceeding with the other steps (couldn't find any in the docs)? Or if not, is there a better way to do what I'm trying to do?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Since my main problem was that I wanted to pull the shared SCSS file used by Vue components from another folder, my solution ended up being the one from this question [vue.config.js to (laravel) webpack.mix.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56019339/vue-config-js-to-laravel-webpack-mix-js)

Basically, I used `globalVueStyles` in mix.options to switch to a different common _variables file, instead of importing it manually in each component.

```
mix.options({
    extractVueStyles: true,
    globalVueStyles: 'resources/sass/' + process.env.MIX_THEME + '/_variables.scss'
});
```